# Cycle Length of the Positive Powers of Two Mod Powers of Ten

Tags: nt.number-theory

I want to prove that the positive powers of two, mod 10<sup>m</sup>, cycle with period 4*5<sup>m-1</sup>. It's simple to prove that the powers of FIVE cycle with this period (2 is a primitive root mod powers of five), but how do you make the leap to powers of TEN?

I'm sure it's something simple -- perhaps related to the Chinese Remainder Theorem -- but I don't see the connection yet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's exactly the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You know that the powers of two have a certain period mod 5^m.  What is their period mod 2^m?

Comment: Their ''period'' would always be 1 (powers are always 0).

Comment: So if M is a number which leaves a residue of 1 mod 5^k, and a residue of 0 mod 2^k, what residue does it leave mod 10^k?

Comment: You mean eventually zero.  Now you know that the residue mod 5^m and the residue mod 2^m uniquely determines the residue mod 10^m by CRT, and you know that one is periodic and the other is eventually constant.  What can you conclude?

Comment: Alon: it varies by k

Qiaochu: sorry, I don't "know" either of those points yet. That is my question! (BTW, I'm not a student doing a homework assignment)

Comment: Sure I can use the CRT for the individual cases. For example, the powers of two mod 5 are 2, 4, 3, 1. I can set up four pairs of equations: x==2 mod 5 and x==0 mod 2, x==4 mod 5 and x==0 mod 2, x==3 mod 5 and x==0 mod 2, and x==1 mod 5 and x==0 mod 2. This gives 2, 4, 8, 6 mod 10, respectively -- a cycle of 4. How do I generalize to mod 5^k and mod 2^k?

Comment: OK, so the powers of 2 mod 2^m cycle with period 1 (starting at 2^m), and the powers of 2 mod 5^m cycle with period 4*5<sup>m-1</sup>. To get the powers of 2 mod 10^m, the answer seems to be to multiply the two periods: 1 x 4*5<sup>m-1</sup> = 4*5<sup>m-1</sup>. But what specifically about the CRT lets me do that? The statements of the CRT I've seen talk about the residues, not the periods.

Maybe I need to invoke an underlying theorem from group theory instead?

Comment: All you need to know is that there exists a bijective function CRT(a, b) which given a residue mod 2^k and a residue mod 5^k spits out a unique residue mod 10^k.  Now you have a sequence CRT(a_n, b_n) with the property that a_n is periodic with period 4*5^{m-1} and b_n is eventually constant.  What is the period of CRT(a_n, b_n)?  (There is nothing deep going on here.)

Comment: "What is the period of CRT(a_n, b_n)?" -- that's the million dollar question. The answer seems "obvious," but if you were writing a proof, say ANSWERING a mathoverflow question that people would vote on for best answer -- what would you write? Are you using LCMs? A result from group theory? I'm looking for something concrete.

Comment: Because CRT is bijective and b_n is eventually constant, for all but finitely many n we have CRT(a_n, b_n) = CRT(a_m, b_m) if and only if n = m, hence the period of CRT(a_n, b_n) is equal to the period of a_n.  Again, there's nothing deep going on here; bijections preserve period.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "if and only if a_n = a_m."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer I like best is based on the proof in the "physics forums" thread linked to in the comments above. I wrote about it in detail here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/cycle-length-of-powers-of-two-mod-powers-of-ten/

Comment: From the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question... Also, we recommend not answering your own question immediately since leaving the question "open" encourages other people to respond to it. You might discover that somebody else has an even better answer!"


I think waiting 23 days for other answers was sufficient. Also, I cited a source upon which I based my answer, but it was given in piecemeal fashion in a forum thread. I wrote an article to try to present the answer clearly -- and it was long with lots of math notation -- so I cited it here instead of copying it.

Comment: This is also from the FAQ: "you don't earn any reputation for accepting your own answer to a question".  So in other words, they're implying it's OK to accept your own answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Reverting (i.e. +1)

Answer (score 3):

And if you insist, let me write this out in detail.  All you need is the following lemma.

**Lemma:**  Let f(n) be periodic with period p and let g be injective.  Then g(f(n)) is periodic with period p.

*Proof.*  Clearly g(f(n+p)) = g(f(n), so g(f(n)) has some period q dividing p.  On the other hand, g(f(n+q)) = g(f(n)) for all n if and only if f(n+q) = f(n) for all n by injectivity, so q = p.

As I remarked above we have b<sub>n</sub> = b for all but finitely many n and x -> CRT(x, b) is an injection.  The result follows.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. (I got another answer at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=2400449#post2400449 which you might want to check out. It appeals to me more because it uses algebra and exponent arithmetic and does not use the CRT explicitly.)